# Call Bundle Activator Before Injecting Entity Manager

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, apache-karaf

I have a persistence bundle (has a `Meta-Persistence`), it also has an `Activator` class

when deployed into `karaf`, the container starts processing the `persistence unit` &`mapping files` etc, before calling the `start` method of the `Activator`

My question is : is there a way to alter this behavior ? having the container call the method first ?

#### Edit

The reason I need the activator to be called first:

I have some `mapped entities` that rely on `jackson` which itself relies on `spring`, what happens is, when `hibernate` is loading the `entities`, it arrives at a home-made class that blocks while no `spring context` is injected into it. So the bundle is forever on a `starting` state

So I though a possible solution would be to make use of the `Activator` to inject the `spring context`

Thank you

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want your Activator to run first?

Comment: I added the reason in the original post

Comment: Jackson typically does not require spring. Or do you try to expose REST services directly from an entity .. which I would rather not do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container (or more precisely Aries JPA) must start processing the persistence unit before the bundle is started.

The reason is that Aries JPA needs to do load time weaving in some cases. This kind of weaving must be done before classes to be weaved are loaded the first time by any bundle. So the only safe time to do this is directly after the bundle is resolved.

Comment: So this seems like a chicken & egg thing, any suggestion ?

Comment: Generally it is a big problem to use dependency injection in entity classes. I would try to extract that functionality in a service class that only uses the entity.

Comment: I ended up creating another bundle that creates the context and exports it,  that solved the problem